# How to get variables from lists object?

Tags: python, list, class, object

How to get variables from a lists object?

For example:

```
class Ball(object):

    def __init__ (self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

ball = Ball(x, y)
list = [ball]
```

Is it something like this?:

```
a = list[0]
b = list[1]
```

So the `print(a, b)` would print `x, y`?

Comment: `print(ball.x, ball.y)`?

Comment: What about `list = [ball.x, ball.y]`?

Comment: `print(list[0].x, list[0].y)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Ball(object):

    def __init__ (self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def display(self):
        return self.x, self.y


ball = Ball('This is x value', 'This is y value')
a, b = ball.display()
print a, b
```

`__init__` should always return `None` so you have to create a new method to return x and y.

You can't try to return from `__init__` method like this:

```
class Ball(object):

    def __init__ (self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        return self.x, self.y

a, b = Ball('This is x value', 'This is y value')
print a, b
```

Would give you exception as:

```
TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'tuple'
```

Comment: @Matiss If you feel this answer was helpful than please raise and  accept it. Or if you need any change in the answer kindly include in your comment.

Comment: But if I put the `object` in a `List` then how could I call it out from the `List`?

Comment: Actually we are not inserting object in a list. We just created a new method which returns both self.x and self.y for us. The purpose of creating a new method was because `__init__` method always returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Ball(object):

    def __init__ (self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    # add method to get points as tuple (x, y)     
    def get_point(self):
        return (self.x, self.y,)



ball = Ball(x, y)
```

This creates a list with a single Ball object in index 0
(name changed so you won't override [builtin](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list) `list`):

```
ball_list = [ball]
```

This will create the `[x, y]` using the method we added and a cast from `tuple` to `list`:

```
ball_point = list(ball.get_point())
```